# Area of circles on a wall

Tags: geometry, area

If you are painting a wall that is 10 ft by 12ft blue with gray polka dots on it, and the polka dots are spaced their diameter's distance away from each other at the shortest distance, how much paint of each color should you buy?

Comment: We can made up a diameter and drew a picture of what it would look like on the wall. We thought we would subtract out the circle areas from the overall area of the wall but thought that there is probably an easier way to do this-- maybe some kind of ratio-- that would work no matter what diameter the circles are...

Comment: That is a good question, if the ratio of dot color area to wall color area is dependent on the dot diameter. Why not try to calculate it for two samples, one with large dots one with small dots?

Comment: That's exactly what we were thinking-- just hope we can find some graph paper and draw it out correctly and then compare... If anyone knows of a simpler way to do this please fill us in!!!!

Comment: Assume a 2 x 2 cell with one big dot of $d=2$. Calculate the ratio of the dot area by the cell area. Now divide it into four 1x1 cells with one dot of diameter $d=1$ each. Again calculate the ratio of the area of the dots by the area of the cells. Compare.

Comment: Yes, the ratios are equal. I will now draw it two ways with the circles spaced a diameter apart and should also get the same ratio, which I can then apply to figure it out. Thanks for helping us work through and clarify our thinking on this!

Comment: Square lattice or hexagonal lattice?